# Check if a row from DataGridView exists in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which is populating data from every disk of my network splitted by partition. I want to insert it into my database, but I don't know how I can validate how many rows I have into the `DataGridView`.

This is the code I already have:

```
try
{
    con = new OleDbConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();

    string queryInsert = @"INSERT INTO tblComputers
        (Partition1Disk, Type1Disk, TotalSpace1Disk, 
        UseSpace1Disk, FreeSpace1Disk, PercentageUse1Disk, Partition2Disk, Type2Disk, TotalSpace2Disk, 
        UseSpace2Disk, FreeSpace2Disk, PercentageUse2Disk, Partition3Disk, Type3Disk, TotalSpace3Disk, 
        UseSpace3Disk, FreeSpace3Disk, PercentageUse3Disk,Partition4Disk, Type4Disk, TotalSpace4Disk, 
        UseSpace4Disk, FreeSpace4Disk, PercentageUse4Disk)
        VALUES
        (@Partition1Disk, @Type1Disk, @TotalSpace1Disk, @UseSpace1Disk, @FreeSpace1Disk, @PercentageUse1Disk, 
        @Partition2Disk, @Type2Disk, @TotalSpace2Disk, @UseSpace2Disk, @FreeSpace2Disk, @PercentageUse2Disk, 
        @Partition3Disk, @Type3Disk, @TotalSpace3Disk, @UseSpace3Disk, @FreeSpace3Disk, @PercentageUse3Disk,
        @Partition4Disk, @Type4Disk, @TotalSpace4Disk, @UseSpace4Disk, @FreeSpace4Disk, @PercentageUse4Disk)";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryInsert);
        cmd.Connection = con;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        cmd.Parameters["@Partition1Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@Type1Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@TotalSpace1Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@UseSpace1Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@FreeSpace1Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@PercentageUse1Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        cmd.Parameters["@Partition2Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@Type2Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@TotalSpace2Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@UseSpace2Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@FreeSpace2Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@PercentageUse2Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        cmd.Parameters["@Partition3Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@Type3Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@TotalSpace3Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@UseSpace3Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@FreeSpace3Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@PercentageUse3Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        cmd.Parameters["@Partition4Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@Type4Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@TotalSpace4Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@UseSpace4Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@FreeSpace4Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@PercentageUse4Disk"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

The problem is that some of the computers from my Network only have one partition and when it happens, the application will display an error saying that index is out of bounds. There is any validation that I can do to see when there is only one or a maximum of 4 rows into the `DataGridView` and depending on that insert a null into that column?

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows.Count` ...?

Comment: I've updated my post with it, check if possible @sab669

Comment: I assume you have 4 DataGridViews and the code above is wrong ?   I see you add the values from the same gridview for all 4 partition disks.